# How do you programatically create multiple compile-time defs in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to create multiple defs in a file at compile time without having to type everything out.  I'd like to do something like:

```
(ns itervals)

(loop [i 0]
   (if (<= i 128)
       (do 
         (def (symbol (str "i" i)) i)
         (recur (+ i 1)))))
```

In that way, we define the variables i1,..., i128 in the current context.  I can't figure out a way to do it at compile time without defining them all explicitly.  I think macros might be the way to go, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Is there a pressing reason not to just use an array?

Comment: Ditto, polluting your namespace like this is usually not a good sign.  You could use a toplevel vector or hashmap.  Or perhaps rework your code not to need to refer to a toplevel data structure at all.

Comment: These values will be used hundreds, if not thousands of times in a single program, so having a convenient syntax in their own namespace is simply more convenient and clear than anything else.  Doing something like (iadd (inttype 32) 3 4) thousands times (where I may have to look up the cached value) is simply less efficient and clear than (iadd ty/i32 3 4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feels more like compile time:

```
(defmacro multidef[n]   
    `(do ~@(for [i (range n)]
           `(def ~(symbol (str "i" i)) ~i))))

(multidef 128)

i0   ; 0 
i127 ; 127 
i128 ; unable to resolve
```

But I can't think of a test that will tell the difference, so maybe the distinction is false.

Comment: Turns out that while Jeff's version works in the REPL, it doesn't compile correctly when running unit tests.

Comment: That's probably the laziness of the for statement. Perhaps if you use doall or dotimes or doseq it will work?

Comment: That's probably the problem with Jeff's solution (aside from the gross-ness of doing this with eval at runtime). Just chiming in to say that John's is definitely the right way to do it, and that you should keep in mind the `(do ~@(whatever)) form - it turns out to be a pattern that's used in a lot of macros. If you find it more readable, you can also write it as (cons 'do (whatever))

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
(for [i (range 1 129)]
    (eval `(def ~(symbol (str "i" i)) ~i)))
```